# Is available FastReport in C++Builder Community Edition (version 10.4.2)?

Tags: fastreport

I can not find FastReport in Getit Manage in my C++ Builder.

My C++ builder is Community Edition(version 10.4.2).

Is available FastReport in  C++Builder Community Edition (version 10.4.2)?

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score -1):

Download it from here and install
https://www.fast-report.com/en/fastreport-embarcadero-edition/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32678301)